# D3 Scatter points don't line up with x-axis

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to plot a time scale using D3. However, the scatter points don't line up with the x-axis. They are offset slightly to the right. Any suggestions?

https://jsfiddle.net/kevinjhc/maaek6tb/1/

```
var data = [
  {
    date: "2016-05-22T09:33:57-04:00",
    value: 80
  }
]

var x = d3.time.scale()
          .domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return new Date(d.date); }))
          .range([ 0, width ]);

g.selectAll("scatter-dots")
    .data(data)
    .enter().append("svg:circle")
      .attr("cx", function (d) { return x( new Date(d.date) ); } )
      .attr("cy", function (d) { return y(d.value); } )
      .attr("r", 8);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

did some origin correction. The circles get drawn from the left-top co-ordiates... so u have to translate them to draw them from center:

```
 g.selectAll("scatter-dots")
.data(data)
.enter().append("svg:circle")
    .attr("cx", function (d) { return x( new Date(d.date) ); } )
    .attr("cy", function (d) { return y(d.value); } )
    .attr('transform', 'translate('+ -rad/2 +  ',' + -rad/2 + ')')
    .attr("r", rad);
```

check: https://jsfiddle.net/maaek6tb/3/

also corrected the focus lines... as they need to be translated accordingly too.